# Switching between Navigators using a SwitchNavigator (React Navigation)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a simple navigation setup. I would like to have a `StackNavigator` for my authentication routes and a `TabNavigator` for the other content.
I created both of this navigators:

```
const PreContentNavigator = createStackNavigator({ // Non auth routes
    Landing: {
        screen: Landing
    },
    LogIn: {
        screen: LogIn
    },
    SignUp: {
        screen: SignUp
    }
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null
    }
});

const ContentNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({ // Auth routes
    Dashboard: {
        screen: Dashboard
    },
    Library: {
        screen: Library
    },
    Settings: {
        screen: Settings
    }
});
```

I have linked both of these up wit `SwitchNavigator`, because that seems to be the recommended way of doing it according to the docs. The code for that looks like the following:

```
const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    PreContent: {
        screen: PreContentNavigator
    },
    Content: {
        screen: ContentNavigator,
    }
});
```

Now, this seems to work, but there is a pretty big issue. At one point, I want to navigate the user from the `PreContentNavigator` to the `ContentNavigator`. I tried that in my `Landing` page:

```
const Landing = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.body}>
            <TouchableHighlight>
                <Text>Nextbook</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight>
                <Text>Log In</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight>
                <Text>Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Content"/*"LogIn"*/)}> // Using LogIn does work!
                <Text>Skip for now...</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
};
```

The problem is that this simply doesn't work. BUT I am able to navigate from routes inside my `PreContentNavigator` to other routes in `PreContentNavigator` (see comment in code).
I feel like [the example on the official plugin page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) uses the exact same principle as I am using. So could any one point out where I am missing something?

Comment: Is using both a stack and a bottom navigator in a switch supported? The example uses 2 stacks. Your code doesn't show the imports or the export of the switch component.. ensure these are correct..

Comment: Also,  remove the commented part from that line of code. I had issues with comments in code (unless they were on a separate line) in react native. You're missing this. from before props? (this.props.navigation.navigate etc.. )

Comment: @RachelGallen I do not see why it wouldn't be. Docs do not mention it as an example.

Comment: can you try navigating to a screen inside Content stack and not use "Content" as the screen name? E.g. navigate("Library")

Comment: @needsleep No luck with that either.